# Get-AzureADUser filter - for special characters

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I have a list of email saved in a text file to check for account status (AccountEnabled). I wrote a simple script and although I got all the results, the error on the screen is bothering me. Some of them have special character.

```
$result = get-azureaduser -filter "mail eq '$user'"
```

The error shown: (email below was edited for privacy)

```
get-azureaduser : Error occurred while executing GetUsers 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Syntax error at position 35 in 'mail eq 'test.y'ng@domain.com''.
RequestId: 9b72f5ae-213d-43dd-a89d-6c71828d5aa7
DateTimeStamp: Wed, 07 Dec 2021 13:22:37 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:9 char:15
+     $result = get-azureaduser -filter "mail eq '$user'"
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUser
```

Comment: See if escaping the quote helps: `$user = $user.Replace("'","\'")` => `get-azureaduser -filter "mail eq '$user'"`

Comment: Tried that and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get info from "mail eq '$user'" all my users, this field is empty.

```
$result = get-azureaduser -filter "userPrincipalName eq '$user'"
```

This works for me.

Comment: That depends. I have a list of email to look for. Some of them have quote ' in the mail. I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: I was reading online and this is what I found the mail attribute is tied to "Exchange Online" account, please look at Exchange Online and see if the "Mail" field has the same misspelled mail field.